# PHP Mysql echoing data in one column from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL table looks like this:

[image: MySQL Table]

and I want to retrieve the data from the column 'host' from where uid is equal to twenty.

I have some code that will connect to the database and will return the row when uid is equal to twenty

DB.php:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function results(){
    return $this->_results;
}
```

server.php:

```
public static function get($uid){
    $_db = DB::getInstance();
    $data = $_db->get('servers', array('uid', '=', $uid));

    return $data->results();
}
```

cURL.php:

```
$a = Server::get('20');
var_dump($a);
```

The var_dump on the return gives the following:
[image: PHP var_dump return]

> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (4) { ["sid"]=> string(2) "13" ["host"]=> string(12) "example.home" ["port"]=> string(4) "8081" ["uid"]=> string(2) "20" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4) { ["sid"]=> string(3) "153" ["host"]=> string(15) "stream.as.ag.ca" ["port"]=> string(5) "23434" ["uid"]=> string(2) "20" } }

*Note:
If this question has already been answered somewhere else, could a link be provided as I couldn't find the answer.*

Comment: Actually I zoomed in so nevermind, might be useful for other users to be able to see it though. The data is there are you having issues iterating through it? Look into `foreach`.

Comment: Yes, I have issues on how to go through the data and then extract the 'host'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to pull each host with this.

```
foreach($a as $row) {
    echo $row->host;
}
```

Comment: It's returning the following error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in cURL.php at the line echo $data

Comment: Hmm haven't used the `FETCH_OBJ` before, how about this update?

Comment: what are you referring to?